# Dois leitores no arduino

Tags: c, c++, arduino

como esse código em leio o cartão e informo se esta cadastrado ou não. Agora preciso inserir dois leitores rfid no Arduíno. Como adicionar o segundo leitor rfid nesse código?

```
include SPI.h
include MFRC522.h

define LED_VERDE 6
define LED_VERMELHO 7
define BUZZER 8
define SS_PIN 10
define RST_PIN 9

String IDtag = ""; 
bool Permitido = false;  
String TagsCadastradas[] = {"ID_1"};
MFRC522 LeitorRFID(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);             
    SPI.begin();                     
    LeitorRFID.PCD_Init();          
    pinMode(LED_VERDE, OUTPUT);     
    pinMode(LED_VERMELHO, OUTPUT);  
    pinMode(BUZZER, OUTPUT);        
}

void loop() {  
    Leitura();  
}
```

Comment: Possivelmente instanciando outro objeto do tipo `MFRC522`.

Comment: e aqui: LeitorRFID.PCD_Init();  não teria nada?

Comment: Teria a chamada de `PCD_Init` da outra instância

Comment: Conforme o usuário [Rodrigo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64727/rodrigo) sugeriu, uma ajuda mais precisa para seu problema possivelmente será encontrada na comunidade sobre [Arduino](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MFRC522` é uma [classe](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/blob/master/src/MFRC522.h), portanto, basta instanciar dois objetos distintos dessa classe.

**Instanciando**:

```
MFRC522 LeitorRFID(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);
MFRC522 LeitorRFID2(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);
```

**Utilizando**:

```
LeitorRFID.PCD_Init(); 
LeitorRFID2.PCD_Init();
```

Note que agora existem dois objetos do tipo `MFRC522`, um chamado `LeitorRFID` e outro `LeitorRFID2`.

Sua maneira de nomear a variável pode confundir um pouco. O melhor seria nomear a variável seguindo o padrão [Camel Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case), pois em C, C++ é normalmente assim que se faz e a linguagem do Arduino é C++. Assim, ao invés de `MFRC522 LeitorRFID(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);` seria `MFRC522 leitorRFID(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);`